# Accessing nested JavaScript properties via custom dynamic method

Tags: javascript, methods, dynamic, properties, nested

Given this JavaScript object, I want to access their nested properties via dynamic method starting with **'get' + a CamelCased attribute name** (of course the attribute must be defined in the inital object)

As far as I know, this can be achieved by using a Proxy object + recursion, but I need your input anyway.

Best regards!

```js
function Order() {
    this.no = 'n1234';
    this.info = {
        customer: {
            ID: 'c1234'
            address: {
                //...
                shiping: {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var order = new Order();

// The expected result should be:
// order.no = order.getNo()
// order.info = order.getInfo()
// order.info.customer or order.info.getCustomer() or order.getInfo().customer or order.getInfo().getCustomer()
// and so on for all nested attributes
```

This is the snippet I prepared, but it doesn't seem to work for nested properties.

```js
function createProxy(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (typeof target[prop] === 'object' && target[prop] !== null) {
        return createProxy(target[prop]);
      }
      if (prop.startsWith('get')) {
        const propName = prop.charAt(3).toLowerCase() + prop.slice(4);
        if (target[propName] !== undefined) {
          return () => target[propName];
        }
      }
      return target[prop];
    },
  });
}

function Order() {
  const properties = {
    no: 'n1234',
    info: {
      customer: {
        ID: 'c1234'
      }
    }
  };

  return createProxy(properties);
}

var order = new Order();

// order.getInfo().customer - { ID: 'c1234' }
// order.getInfo().getCustomer() - TypeError: order.getInfo().getCustomer is not a function"
```

Comment: So you want something to automatically define mothods like `getNo()`? Why do you need that when you can just write `order.no`?

Comment: For the proxy, you'd need to add a proxy to al the nested objects. I don't think a proxy for `order` will be used when you access a nested property.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I need a code to make it possible. Both should work

Comment: You seem to know that you have to create proxies. Show what you tried.

Comment: The snippet is provided in the modified post.

Comment: As I said, the proxy for the top-level object won't work for nested objects. You need to create proxies for every level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution. Thanks to [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) and 
[Alexander Nenashev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14098260/alexander-nenashev)

```js
/**
 * @param {Object} obj
 * @returns {Proxy} obj
 */
function createProxy(obj) {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get(target, prop) {
            function out() {
                if (Object.getPrototypeOf(target[prop]) === Object.prototype) {
                    return createProxy(target[prop]);
                } else {
                    return target[prop];
                }
            }

            if (!prop.startsWith('get')) {
                return out();
            }

            var property = prop[3] + prop.slice(4);

            if (property.valueOf().toUpperCase() === property.valueOf()) {
                prop = property;
                return out;
            } else {
                prop = prop[3].toLowerCase() + prop.slice(4);
                return out
            }
        },
    });
}

function Order() {
    this.no = 'n1234';
    this.info = {
        customer: {
            ID: 'c1234',
            address: {
                shipping: {
                    ID: 's4354654'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return createProxy(this);
}

var order = new Order();

console.log(order.no) // "n1234"
console.log(order.getNo()) // "n1234"
console.log(order.info.getCustomer().getID()) // "c1234"
console.log(order.getInfo().customer.ID) // "c1234"
console.log(order.info.customer.getAddress().getShipping().ID) // "s4354654"
console.log(order.getInfo().getCustomer().address.getShipping().getID()) // "s4354654"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tweaks would help, the main is to return a proxy from `getXXX()` calls too:

```js
const createProxy = (obj) => new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop) {
    const out = () => target[prop]?.__proto__ === Object.prototype ? createProxy(target[prop]) : target[prop];
    return prop.startsWith?.('get') && (prop = prop[3].toLowerCase() + prop.slice(4)) ? out : out();
  },
});

function Order() {
  const properties = {
    no: 'n1234',
    info: {
      customer: {
        ID: 'c1234',
        title: 'Bad customer'
      }
    }
  };

  return createProxy(properties);
}

var order = new Order();

console.log(order.getInfo());
console.log(order.getInfo().getCustomer().getTitle());
console.log(order.info.getCustomer().ID);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is useful. I only see that getID() can not be resolved and returns undefined. Anyway, I modified your code so that I get the expected result.